# Using `NSTextAttachment` in SwiftUI `Text`

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

Does SwiftUI `Text` not work with `NSTextAttachment`? I have this `AttributedString`:

```swift
var attributedString: AttributedString {
    var sampleAttributedString = AttributedString(sampleText)
    // Apply some bold and italics attributes to sampleAttributedString
     ...
    // create NSMutableAttributedString
    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(sampleAttributedString)
    let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    image1Attachment.image = UIImage(named: "audio.png")
    let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)
    mutableAttributedString.append(imageString)
    mutableAttributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "End of text"))

    sampleAttributedString = AttributedString(mutableAttributedString)

    return sampleAttributedString
}
```

When I use the above in a SwiftUI view as follows:

```
var body: some View {
    Text(attributedString)
}
```

The image I embedded above does not show up. All the other text renders as expected. The `catch` isn't called. The image is in assets, I've tried with system images too.

The same logic works if I set the same attributed string to the `attributedText` property of a `UILabel`.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching how to do this in swiftUI too and I found this post

https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/insert-image-into-swiftui-text

here is an example of how use it:

```
(Text("This image")
  + Text(Image("icon")) // HERE
  + Text("is our logo."))
    .font(.title)
```

hope this helps